# Viewing Results from Neo4j Bolt Driver

Tags: c#, neo4j

I am trying to use the official C# drive for Neo4j (the one using the Bolt binary protocol instead of the http one from Neo4jClient).

Tried this

```
  using (ISession session = driver.Session())
  {
    IStatementResult results = session.Run("MATCH (n) RETURN DISTINCT LABELS(n) AS Label");

    var resultsTemp = results.ToList();

    foreach (var record in resultsTemp)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}", record.Values["Label"]);
    }

  }
```

But I am just getting this:

```
Hello System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]
Hello System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]
Hello System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]
Hello System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]
```

What am I missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

LABELS(n) returns a list for each node n (nodes can have multiple labels), so your final result is a list of lists. You'll need to output the string representation of each list. And yes that still applies even if you're using DISTINCT, as multi-labeled nodes will still return as a list of each of its labels.